# Java - Reflection, casting to an unknown Object?

Tags: java, swing, reflection, casting

Basically, I scan through all components in a JFrame, checking if it has the method setTitle(String arg0), if it does, then set it's title to "foo". However, in order to set it's title I need to cast it to a suitable object.

```
    public void updateTitle(Container root){

        for (Component c : root.getComponents()){

            String s = "";
            for (Method m : c.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()){

                s += m.getName();
            }

            if (s.contains("setTitle")){                

                c.setTitle("foo"); //Here is where I need the casting 
            }

            if (c instanceof Container){

                updateTitle((Container) c);
            }
        }           
    }
```

Problem is, I don't know what class is it. Is there any way to cast it to itself, or I should try doing something else?

Comment: Why do you append the names of methods in a string? If some *strange* object had methods named `set` and `Title`, your code would break. Also, the `Method` object in the loop is *exactly* what you'd need to call the `setTitle` method.

Comment: setTitle is description in ToolBar, [JFrame.setTitle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setTitle%28java.lang.String%29), don't to create a bunch of JFrames, use CardLayout, this method is confortable accesible from Casting, same as from Reflection,

Comment: @user1541106 for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, about a few JFrames,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a `Method`, you can use `invoke()` to call it:

```
 for (Method m : c.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()){
     if( "setTitle".equals( m.getName() ) {
         m.invoke( c, "foo" ); // == c.setTitle("foo"); but without the casts
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think it's better to use `getDeclaredMethod("setTitle", String.class)` here to avoid explicit iteration and potential bug if there are 2 versions of `setTitle` method with different arguments.

Comment: I think, getMethod fits better than getDeclaredMethod: You would get any *public* setTitle-Method, independend if it is declared at the class or any of it's parent classes. getDeclaredMethods returns private methods, too, but only from the specified class, not from it's parents

Answer (score 2):

You can call setTitle() via reflection, not via casting

Comment: I see, but how exactly do I do that? (using reflection it is)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Method m : c.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()){
    if (m.getName().equals("setTitle")) {
        m.invoke(c, "foo");
    }
}
```

Delete all other unnecessary code. Your String `s` is useless (because anyway, it makes no sense to append all method names and check for `contains`. What if the class had methods called `setT` and `itle`?)