# Cast object to unknown data type

Tags: java, casting

I am working on my project where I need to check if a specific value is equal or not to a value on a dataset.

This is the function I'm creating:

```
public void setSingleLimit(String columnName, Object limit){

}
```

where `columnName` is the column of my dataset I will be applying the function to and `limit` is the value used in the equality condition check.

So basically, this function will take the `limit` value and check if all the values in `columnName` are equal or not that value.

However, I do not know before hand the type of the column. I can, however, get the data type of the column in the function.

`dataset.first().get(columnName).getClass()`
gives me the class of the values in a column (we can safely and securely assume all the values in a column will belong to the same class/data type)

I would like to cast the `limit` object received in the function to the columns class type in order to be able to do a comparison.

I KNOW I can override the function so it can accept different values (int, long, Boolean, String, etc.) and that will certainly work. However, I want to create a single method for less complexity and for easy understanding to my end user. We can also securely assume that the user will enter a correct value on the function, meaning that if the column is a column of Strings, the user will NOT put a value that is not a String.

Any idea of how I can cast an object to a class that is not known before hand?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you will have to use java reflection, like [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319760/java-reflection-casting-to-an-unknown-object?rq=1) but I'm not able to to help you further more

Comment: You say you want to check for equality. Why can't you just use `equals(Object o)`? It is declared on `Object` and accepts an `Object` as parameter. The implementation will be bound dynamically at runtime.

Comment: do you know subset of possible types which can go inside? If so then you can create private methods with such parameters and in public method just use `if (limit instanceof <customType>)` or `if (<customType>.getClass().isAssignableFrom(limit.getClass()))`. I know it is so ugly, but you can live with it if there isn't too much types of limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to check for equality. Just use `equals(Object o)`. It is declared on `Object` and accepts an `Object` as parameter. The implementation will be bound dynamically at runtime.

```
public void setSingleLimit(String columnName, Object limit){
    Object columnValue = getValue(columnName);
    limit.equals(columnValue); // If limit can be null, swap variables
}
```

Example:
If `limit` is a `String`, `equals()` from `String` will be used. It doesn't matter if `columnValue` is not a `String` because it will just return `false` in that case.

Just make sure the different `equals()` implmentations do what you want. If you use custom classes you can overwrite it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Without using cast, I would do like that :

```
if(limit instanceof anyDataset) {
//Compare
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `instanceof` comparison to ensure type safety when comparing and casting your object.

For example:

`if (limit instanceof Boolean) {
      // do something
}`

This will avoid `ClassCastException` and ensures you're doing exactly what you want with the exact data-type you're expecting.

More on `instanceof`:

- [use of "Instance of" in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526817/use-of-instance-of-in-java)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html